# RequestDispatcher.forward(req,res) not working

Tags: jsp, servlet-3.0

> Hi,
>   I am working on JSP Servlet Project in that i have created one CommonServlet class, from that i forward request to redirect JSP page my code is like as below

```
Class CommonServlet extends HTTPServlet{
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
super.doGet(req, resp);
String url="/file/myfolder/jsp/login.jsp";
RequestDispatcher  requestDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher(url);
requestDispatcher.forward(req, resp);
 }
}
```

> Web.xml

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>common</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.server.CommonServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>common</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/common/*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But this is not working it will get same common path for all other files.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: post the project structure please

Answer (score 0):

First i'm assuming that you have some `index.jsp` mapping in your `web.xml`

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

So first the server reads the web.xml and it loads the index.jsp when you do

```
http://localhost:8080/yourProjectName
```

In your `index.jsp` have a form which calls the servlet like this

```
<form method="get" action="common" name="form">
<input type="submit" value="LOGIN"/>
</form>
```

Finally in the `doGet()` of yourServletClass
have this to redirect to login.jsp(assuming your login.jsp is under `webcontent/login.jsp`)

```
RequestDispatcher rd=req.getRequestDispatcher("login.jsp");
rd.include(request,response);
```

**Edit** : try something like this
change your url-mapping in `web.xml` to something like

```
<url-pattern>/myservlet</url-pattern>
```

Config for the filter in `web.xml`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>yourFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.yourpackage.YourFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>yourFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/common/*</url-pattern> 
</filter-mapping>
```

Then the filter class

```
public class YourFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

@Override
public void destroy() {
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain fc) 
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    if(url.endsWith(".jsp")) {
      RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/myserlvet");
        dispatcher.forward(req, res);
    }
}

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig fc) throws ServletException {

}}
```

Comment: ya its call index.jsp.but if i want to call commonServlet when my url pattern is like common/*.jsp how to do?

Comment: first why you need `common/*.jsp` it just means that all the jsp under the common folder wants to access the Servlet

Comment: Yes. I have created common servlet to redirect passed JSP only no any other logic in this common servlet.

Comment: but url-pattern shouldnot be like this because it will throw ` java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern>`

Comment: if i do like common/* then it will check for all jsp,js,image so i want to call this servlet for jsp only.can u help me in this

Comment: make the URL patterns ending with "/*". and implement a filter to invoke the servlet only by .jsp files